# NetBeans Platform 6.7 does not run on Java 1.5

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7

I have also posted this question on the netbeans forums - hoping for maximum exposure.

I am developing an application using NetBeans RELEASE67 and maven-nbm plugin.
I use Java WebStart to deploy.

My users have a mixture of java 1.6 and java 1.5

My java 1.5 users are unable to use the software;
on startup the software calls TopComponent.findInstance()
and this results in

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/GroupLayout$Group`

I can see that javax.swing.GroupLayout is new to java 1.6+, and am stumped that the basic TopComponent code is so tied to java 1.6.

How can I get a NetBeans platform app to run under Java 1.5?

I will try to rewind to RELEASE65 in the hope this will solve the problem.
Any suggestions?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the slow response.

My problem was that I was running the IDE under Java 6, and Matisse had created all the layouts using the java6 only class javax.swing.GroupLayout.

I didn't notice the problem until I had to run the software on the minoritiy of my clients who are stuck on Java 1.5

This is easily fixed using the following procedure

- Open the TopComponent in the 'Inspector' window
- Right-click on the root node (Form TopComponent). Select the 'Properties Windo
- In the properties window there is a line about 'Layout Generation Style'. The choice is between

  - Standard Java 6 Code
  - Swing Layout Extensions Library
- Select the latter option.
- Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Are you including swing-layout.jar in your deployment? You'll need that for running on pre-Java 6 platforms.

Comment: Yes, that was one dimension of the problem. I've put in my full solution as an answer